# Are you on something me? - (making riddles rhyme is hard)

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

```
Do you think me of little worth, do I live in a tree,

I have a theory on the earth, are you on something me,

Not the nicest thing to speak when you describe a friend,

Could I make a lighter load or might that break or bend,

And without me, a victory is said to be much sweeter,

But with a point I'm deadlier, and maybe even neater.
```

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is

> Hollow

Do you think me of little worth,

> Hollow can be a synonym for worthless as in "hollow victory"

do I live in a tree,

> A tree hollow is a cavity in a tree which may provide a habitat for animals.

I have a theory on the earth, are you on something me,

> [Hollow Earth Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Earth). Are you on something hollow?

Not the nicest thing to speak when you describe a friend,

> Hollow can mean insincere as in a "hollow compliment".

Could I make a lighter load

> To hollow out is to make a hole in something which would make a lighter load.

or might that break or bend,

> Having a hole in something might break it. Also a hollow can refer to a concavity or depression which would appear as a bend.

And without me, a victory is said to be much sweeter,

> A hollow victory is a victory that inflicts such a heavy toll on the victor as to not be sweet at all.

But with a point I'm deadlier, and maybe even neater.

> Hollow-point bullets are designed to increase in diameter once within a target making them extremely deadly but also superficially neat.

Comment: Oh, well played!

Comment: Promise could have been compliment for a slightly better fit, but As Paul said, "Well played!"  Great descriptions too.   :)  +1